# Run Jasper report and export as pdf from Java Swing application

Tags: java, xml, swing, jasper-reports

I have made a Java Swing application which produces an xml file with data from a mysql database.

Using that I have successfully made a Jasper `(jrxml)` report using the `Jasper 5.5.0` plugin for NetBeans separately from my Swing application.

To do this I use the prepared xml file as datasource. So I have Jasper report with an xml  datasource and one subreport. How can I run that `.jasper` report from my Swing application and export as a pdf file? As a final message box from my Swing app I get:

```
<em>"XML file is successfully generated"</em>
```

I want to make one button on that message box with option:

```
<em>"Print xml to pdf file"</em>
```

Where can I run my Jasper report and export as a pdf?

I have searched for examples using Google, but I can't find anything useful.

Comment: no worries... just a heads up, you should probably try and expand the question to show what you have tried. I know you say you have "searched for examples using Google" but without putting something more in the question it will likely be closed.

Comment: @Fraser thanks for support, I will be find something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReportsContext;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource;
public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
     HashMap hm = new HashMap < > ();
      String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\somexmldatasource.xml";
      InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
      JRXmlDataSource ds = new JRXmlDataSource(inputStream, "/some/xpath/query");
      JasperReport jasperReport;
      JasperPrint jasperPrint;
      jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\yourreport.jrxml");
      jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, hm, ds);
      JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "someoutputpath\\simple_report.pdf");
 } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }

}
```

for using Jasper in java you must include several JARs from:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-5.5.0\ireport\modules\ext\
```

(or some other path of iReport app)

The JARs to include are:

- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-digester-2.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.jar
- jasperreports-5.5.0.jar
- xml-apis.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar
- servlet-api-2.4.jar
- iText-2.1.7.js2.jar